# Specifying virtual keyboard type for EditText in XML

Tags: android, android-edittext, virtual-keyboard

I'm creating a ListActivity.  In each list item I have a View I've created which contains a RatingBar and an EditText.  In the screenshot at the bottom, you can see the virtual keyboard contains a returnline key and no "Done" key.  I would like to specify a different style of keyboard to use (and hopefully retain the spell checking bar).  I would like my virtual keyboard to have a "Done" key instead of a return key.  Can I set the style of virtual keyboard I'm wanting in the EditText's XML?  If so, how?

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try android:imeOptions or TextView#setImeOptions(). Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions).

Comment: This works better than my other solution (my other solution caused a bug).

However, I do have two problems:
1) When I click the EditText to bring up the keyboard, the EditText loses focus and I have to click it again.
2) When I click "Done" on the virtual keyboard, the focus goes to my RatingBar.  I do not want this to happen; so I've set the RatingBar's clickable and focusable attributes to false, but you can still focus on it :\

I suspect both problems are related.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
```

does mostly what I want.  It only allows me to have my EditText be 1 row, though.