# Android EditText listener enter

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, enter

I have a EditText ans I put an `OnEditorActionListener` to do something when enter is pressed. My silly question is: how to make the ENTER key green like in Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I found here:

[Specifying virtual keyboard type for EditText in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462107/specifying-virtual-keyboard-type-for-edittext-in-xml)

**Play around with [ime options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)**

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the help. I solved it by putting `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` and `android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"` in the layout as attributes to the EditText. Both are necessary!

Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but you can try [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html) (section "EditText").